# specific event listeners objective-c

Tags: objective-c, event-listener

I am developing an iPhone app (in Objective-C), and I am trying to make it so that there is some sort of *'action listener'* that is constantly checking to see if the current date and time match that of the first object in a `NSMutableArray` filled with event objects (retrieved from the users calendar).

**My problem** is that I cannot figure out how to do so, while the rest of my code continues to run, because right now I have a `for` loop running to constantly check, which stops my code, and prevents the app from continuing to run. If anyone knows any sort of tutorials, or has an explanation, I would greatly appreciate it.

***Thanks!***

Comment: can you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I am trying to have an 'independent' piece of code (that doesn't interfere with the other code/processes), which will constantly check to see if the current date and time match that of an event/date object(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a NSTimer to fire at the desired date.
This NSTimer category here is useful for this purpose: https://github.com/adamjernst/NSTimer-AbsoluteFireDate

You can also try to create and schedule a [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get notified at a specific date.

Comment: Thanks!, but it appears that this only works when the application is in the foreground, where I need it to work in ALL states. For example, the user should be notified when a certain date and time has been reached, even if they don't have my app open in the foreground.

Comment: In this case try UILocalNotification. It also works in the background.

Comment: Great!...I'm trying to read/understand the Apple Documentation for UILocalNotification, but like most of the Apple Documentations, it is very hard to understand, but hopefully I can make something out of it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `NSTimer` EDIT: see phix23's answer for a more reliable "fireDate" code for use with iOS.

Apple Documentation: [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Comment: Thanks alot!!!  I think my answer lies in the combined use of NSThread(s), NSRunLoop(s), and NSTimer(s)

Comment: There is no need to check the date periodically. You can setup NSTimer  to fire at the exact time you want. See my answer.

Comment: @phix23 yeah that category you linked is useful, good call. voted yours up!

Answer (score 0):

get the time between the current time and the event time, and use dispatch_after

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, timeDifference * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //Your code
});
```